# Method to get Google Form data into multiple rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a google form to collect - **Family Group** Name and **Family member** details.

I get the whole data in one row. [image]

Is there a way to get the data saved in the format in the image through some add in etc.. ? say mapping Family member name to a specific column on the google sheet, sex to a sex column in the sheet...

Comment: Question posts on this site should contain only one question otherwise they could be considered too broad and closed.

Comment: FWIW I don't think this question is too broad, it is only asking a single question: how to group similar data from a form entry that exists as a single row. I do think you'd need a bit of Apps Script help here to iterate over the row data, and then map names, ages, etc. and write them to a new sheet or range.

Comment: can there potentially be any number of  people. and are there always only three fields for each person?

Answer (score 1):

```
={OFFSET($A$2,ROUNDDOWN((ROW(A1)-1)/4),0),OFFSET($B$2,ROUNDDOWN((ROW(A1)-1)/4),MOD(ROW(A1)-1,4)*3,1,3)}
```

Dragfill down.

Assumed that:

- There will only be 3 columns (Name,age,sex) per entry.
- There will be a maximum of 4 family members per household.

Comment: Sorry I am semi technical and i get the error - "there is aproblem with this formula.